# Steepest descent method with penalty function

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I'm trying to find the minimum of a function with 3 variables constrained to a few restrictions with 5 variables applying the penalty method in order to optimise it using the steepest descent method with a backtracking algorithm to compute progressively the alphas.

The function and restrictions are the following:

```
min h(A, C, E) = 5.35*C^2+0.83*A*E+37.29*A-40.14
```

subject to:

```
0 <= 85.33+0.0056*B*C+0.00026*A*D-0.0022*C*E <= 92
90 <= 80.51+0.0071*B*E+0.0029*A*B+0.0021*C^2 <= 110
20 <= 9.3+0.0047*C*E+0.0012*A*C+0.0019*C*D <= 25
78 <= A <= 102
33 <= B <= 45
27 <= C <= 45
27 <= D <= 45
27 <= E <= 45
```

(the numbers don't really matter, my question is more from a theoretical point of view)

The remaining whole function to minimise will therefore be:

```
f(A, B, C, D, E)= h (A, C, E) + c*P(A, B, C, D, E)
```

being `P(A, B, C, D, E)=0.5*sum_i(max(0,gi)^2)`

Now, after computing the function to minimise applying the previous formulas in the penalty formula, we need to calculate the gradient vector, which will be:

```
g[0] = -(0.83*E+37.29);
g[1] = 0;
g[2] = -2*5.35;
g[3] = 0;
g[4] = -0.83*A;
```

The issue I have is with the steepest direction - it doesn't tell variables B and D where to go and they will obviously remain in the initial conditions numbers regardless whether they are within the restriction parametres or not. How should I proceed with that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and the minimization problem $\mathbf{P}$ be:

$$
\min_{x, y} \quad f_{0}(x) \\
s.t \quad f_{i}(x, y) \leq 0 \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}. 
$$

One way to find an approximate solution to this problem is using the penalty method, where a series of unconstrained minimization problems $\mathbf{\tilde{P}}_t$ are solved instead, where $\mathbf{\tilde{P}}_t$ is given by:

$$
\min_{x, y} \quad f_{0}(x) + \lambda_t \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I} } g(f_{i}(x, y)), 
$$

where $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an exterior penalty function and $\lambda_t$ is the penalty coefficient of the $t$-th problem. Let $D = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m : f_{i}(x, y) \leq 0 \quad \forall i \in \mathcal{I}\}$ be the feasible set of the main problem, the main idea of this method is to penalize the solutions of $\mathbf{\tilde{P}}_t$ that violate the constraints of the original problem, therefore, we want $g$ to have a large value for a positive input and to be close to zero for a non positive one. Moreover, at each iteration $t$ the value of $\lambda_t$ is updated to bias the solution of the approximated of the unconstrained problem to the feasible set of the original problem.

Back to your question as $g$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$ the gradient of the approximated objective function (i.e. $f_{0}(x) + \lambda_t \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I} } g(f_{i}(x, y))$) will depend on the values of $y$ even though the gradient of the original objective function did not, thus, the values of $y$ (or in the problem you presented $B$ and $D$) will be updated by the steepest descent method.

Comment: Hi @Jvce92 and thanks for your reply! The issue with the gradient of the approximated objective function is that the restrictions will be double given the double inequalities, hence not appearing in the gradient, i.e.:

0 <= 85.33+0.0056*B*C+0.00026*A*D-0.0022*C*E <= 92

This will be modified to appear in the function as: 

{-(85.33+0.0056*B*C+0.00026*A*D-0.0022*C*E) <= 0} and 
{85.33+0.0056*B*C+0.00026*A*D-0.0022*C*E-92 <= 0}

And therefore, when derivating one will be minus the other and none will appear... or am I wrong in this step?

Comment: You must remember that the gradient of the approximate objective function is obtained by deriving $f_0(x) + \lambda_t \sum_{i \in \mathcal{I}} max(0, f_i(x))^{2}$ and not $f_i(x)$ itself